# How to pass Pulumi's Output<T> to the container definition of a task within ecs?

Tags: json, typescript, pulumi, ecs-taskdefinition

A containerDefinition within a Task Definition needs to be provided as a single valid JSON document. I'm creating a generic ECS service that should handle dynamic data. Here is the code:

```
genericClientService(environment: string, targetGroupArn: Output<string>) {
return new aws.ecs.Service(`${this.domainName}-client-service-${environment}`, {
  cluster: this.clientCluster.id,
  taskDefinition: new aws.ecs.TaskDefinition(`${this.domainName}-client-${environment}`, {
    family: `${this.domainName}-client-${environment}`,
    containerDefinitions: JSON.stringify(
      clientTemplate(
        this.defaultRegion,
        this.domainName,
        this.taskEnvVars?.filter((object: { ENVIRONMENT: string }) => object.ENVIRONMENT === environment),
        this.ecrRepositories
      )
    ),
    cpu: "256",
    executionRoleArn: taskDefinitionRole.arn,
    memory: "512",
    networkMode: "awsvpc",
    requiresCompatibilities: ["FARGATE"],
  }).arn,
  desiredCount: 1,
  ...
```

There is a need of information from an already built resource *this.ecrRepositories* which represents a list of ECR repositories needed. The problem here is that let's say you want to retrieve the repository URL and apply the necessary 'apply()' method, it will return an Output<string>. This would be fine normally, but since *containerDefinitions* needs to be a valid JSON document, Pulumi can't handle it since JSON on an Output<T> is not supported;

> Calling [toJSON] on an [Output<T>] is not supported. To get the value of an Output as a JSON value or JSON string consider either: 1: o.apply(v => v.toJSON()) 2: o.apply(v => JSON.stringify(v)) See https://pulumi.io/help/outputs for more details. This function may throw in a future version of @pulumi/pulumi.
> Blockquote

Neither of the suggested considerations above will work as the dynamicly passed variables are wrapped within a toJSON function callback. Because of this it won't matter how you pass resource information since it will always be an Output<T>.

Is there a way how to deal with this issue?

Comment: What are the types of `this.ecrRepositories` and `clientTemplate` return value?

Comment: @MikhailShilkov `clientTemplate` returns an array of objects containing the inputs for the TaskDefinition Resource Properties as documented here: https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/ecs/taskdefinition/.

`this.ecrRepositories` is a pre-defined set of values returned from multiple ECR repositories. I.E.: this.ecrRepositories.clientUrl = this.client.repository.repositoryUrl.apply((url) => url);`

This makes clientUrl (within this.ecrRepositories) an `Output<string>` (needed for 'image' property that is one of the TaskDefinition Resource Properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `clientTemplate` works correctly and the error happens in the snippet that you shared, you should be able to solve it with

```
containerDefinitions: pulumi.all(
    clientTemplate(
        this.defaultRegion,
        this.domainName,
        this.taskEnvVars?.filter((object: { ENVIRONMENT: string }) => object.ENVIRONMENT === environment),
        this.ecrRepositories
  )).apply(JSON.stringify),
```

Comment: Thank you! So this solution waits for all of the multiple outputs to become available and then provides them to the supplied callback, very clever. Works!